# Maximize practice time on electronic drum kit

Tags: technique, drums

I have played on an acoustic drum kit all my life but now I have unfortunately switched to an electronic drum set because I live in an apartment.

How can I maximize my practice time on an electronic drum set without loosing too much technique from acoustic training?

Is there anything else I can do to keep my acoustic technique by using an electronic drum kit?

Comment: Tony Royster Jr. extensively plays electronic Rolands and see if he looses anything. There is nothing unfortunate about electronic drumset playing. It's just different. I would suggest playing intensively for a week on the electronic drums and then rent a rehearsal place with acoustic ones to see where it feels awkward. Other than that, it's a matter of a few days to adapt to one or the other. There will be no technique loss.

Comment: I know drummers who practice on acoustics and perform on electrics. They both use the same technique. The only difference is some electrics aren't as responsive as an acoustic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have played both acoustic and electric drum and have never noticed any technique loss between the two. It's like learning guitar and then hoping that you don't lose your guitar technique when you learn piano. They are different instruments so in reality learning electric drums will only make you better at the other one.

Although, just like anything if you stop practicing you may forget how to do some things (including technique), but nothing you can't pick back up again.  When you go back to acoustic drums I would make sure you have plenty of time to get familiar with the acoustic kit, before performing or recording.

Comment: I would argue it's more like acoustic vs. electric guitar (though i'm not a fabulous guitarist, and barely a drummer). If you can play an acoustic, you can play an electric, and vice-versa, though they feel different due to different size strings, and so respond differently, and there are a few things you can do on one (e.g. volume swells on electric) that you can't do on other. But still close enough it's not a complete loss.